# Mostrar histórico de um WebView em um listView que está em uma outra Activity

Tags: android

Olá, no meu projeto tenho que exibir o histórico de um WebView num ListView, já tenho um código para isso mas só funciona se o ListView e o Webview estiverem na mesma Activity. O que eu quero fazer é isso mas o WebView e o ListView estando em Activitys diferentes. Como prosseguir ?

Comment: Olá Just a Anonymous, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Para melhorar as suas chances de obter uma boa resposta é interessante que você edite sua pergunta e inclua um exemplo de código demonstrando seu problema. Para mais informações de uma olhada em [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).